# Assign property values together in SwiftUI view?

Tags: swift, swiftui, combine

I'm trying to bind properties together in the view and couldn't find anything better specifically for it. This is what I'm doing:

```
struct ContentView: View {
    @ObservedObject var model: MyModel
    @State var selectedID: Int

    var body: some View {
        Picker("Choose", selection: $selectedID) {
              Text("Abc").tag(0)
              Text("Def").tag(1)
              Text("Ghi").tag(2)
        }
        .onChange(of: model.item?.selectedID) {
            selectedID = $0
        }
    }
}
```

Is there a better way to bind properties together?

Comment: You can directly use selectedID from your viewModel by making it `Published` property. So, in the picker you can use viewModel.selectedID. When it is updated It will update your model object (It should be ObservableObject), which will result in triggering the redraw of body property.

Comment: You can do that... but it goes against the principle of a single source of truth

Comment: I'm trying to maintain a unidirectional flow instead of having the view update the model as well

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If it is about *unidirectional flow* then the only change I see needed in provided snapshot is make similar types. Everything else is ok.

```
struct ContentView: View {
    @ObservedObject var model: MyModel
    @State var selectedID: Int?          // << make optional as well !!

    ...
```